# Sending email directly from my OSX app

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, frameworks

I'm working on an OSX app which will handle an opt-in mailing list.  I have a database containing opt-in email addresses, and the goal is for the user to click one button and have the app build a custom email update, then send out an email update to all members of the mailing list.  This would be used for things such as updating fans about a band's performance, etc.

I found lots of information for the iOS mailComposer, but nothing for something comparable in OSX.  I did find a reference to a message framework, but for some reason can not find the documentation for it in the library (I'm sure it must be there somewhere...)  The only other information I found suggested using a mailto: URL, which somewhat defeats the automated process I'm hoping to achieve.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Is there a specific framework I could research to determine how to active this goal?

Comment: About how many recipients are you trying to support, hundreds or thousands?

Comment: Also, do you want the user to provide mail server information, or get that information from Mail.app?

Comment: There is nothing provided by Apple for this in OS X.

Comment: @Noa right now I have a database of just a few hundred, but I can forsee this expanding to be several thousand.  As for the mail information, I could do it either way.  I could pull it from the users default email program (most likely mail) or I could have them enter the smtp server info and password into the preferences and then bypass mail entirely and go direct.  This would probably be the preferred method in case they don't use Apple mail as their primary client..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create and mail your own messages, not going through Apple Mail (or the user's mail client), [perhaps the EdMessage framework will work for you](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/EDFrameworks/)? (<-- and I've linked it for you)